# Mobile App and WooCommerce WordPress website data sync

Tags: android, ios, mobile, woocommerce, synchronization

I have a website build in WordPress WooCommerce, and now an iOS app developed for the same functionality. I want to make is so that if a user registers or makes an order in the app, the same user also will be registered on the website and the order also should be automatically made on the website. Please help, how can I make this work?

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable woocommerce rest api and according to your needs consume the methods available. Have a look at the docs here: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-rest-api/
If you run into a problem while developing it, post again!